# How to replace all word containing a pattern in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I want to replace all words containing a string  in a file using vim. 
how can it be done in vi editor ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the substitution command like this:

```
:%s/before/after/g
```

where

- %s is the substitution
- before is the string to match
- after is the replacement
- g is the global flag (to replace all occurrences)

If you are matching substrings, you can use

```
:%s/\<\w*substr\w*\>/newword/g
```

where

- \< matches the word boundary
- \w* matches a word character (0 or more)
- substr is your substring
- > matches the word boundary end
- newword is the new word to replace
- g is the global replace